# Get value based on row click based php echo row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to get the value based on the row click in this coding? help me please....

```
function addRowHandlers() {
  var tbody = $("#employee-click"); //document.getElementById("employee- 
  click ");
  tbody.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      var url = new URL(window.location.href);
      var no = url.searchParams.get("no");

      window.location.href = "detail.php?no=" + no;

    })
  })
}
```

the

```html
<body  onload="addRowHandlers()">
 
 
 
  <div class="header"><h1>Data Biodata</h1></div>
  <div class="container" >
           <!-- <center> <button style="right:150"> <a href="Biodata.php">Create New</a></button></center>-->
   <table id="employee-grid" class="display" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1"
   width="100%" border="1" style="text-align: justify;">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>SVC NO</th>
      <th>RANK</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>YEAR</th>
      <th>SYSTEM</th>
      <th>COURSE</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      
     </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="0" class="employee-search-input"></td>
      
      <td><input type="text" id="1" class="employee-search-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="7" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="8" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="9" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="10" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="11" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="12" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="13" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="14" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="15" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="16" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="17" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="employee-click">
     <tr>
                        <th>NO</th>
      <th>SVC NO</th>
      <th>RANK</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>YEAR</th>
      <th>SYSTEM</th>
      <th>COURSE</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      
                       
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  
 </body>
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    
    
   var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "dataBiodata.php", // json datasource
     
   
    } );

             
           
          


     
    $("#employee-grid_filter").css("display","none");  // hiding global search box
    
    $('.employee-search-input').on( 'keyup click change', function () {   
     var i =$(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
     var v =$(this).val();  // getting search input value
     dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
    } );
   } );
   
    function addRowHandlers() {
    var tbody = $("#employee-click"); //document.getElementById("employee-click");
    tbody.each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {     
    var url =new URL (window.location.href);
     var no = url.searchParams.get("no");
   //window.location.href ="detail.php?no="+no;
    alert(no);
    
    })
  })
}
```

```html
<body  onload="addRowHandlers()">
 
 
 
  <div class="header"><h1>Data Biodata</h1></div>
  <div class="container" >
           <!-- <center> <button style="right:150"> <a href="Biodata.php">Create New</a></button></center>-->
   <table id="employee-grid" class="display" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1"
   width="100%" border="1" style="text-align: justify;">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>NO</th>
      <th>SVC NO</th>
      <th>RANK</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>YEAR</th>
      <th>SYSTEM</th>
      <th>COURSE</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      
     </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="0" class="employee-search-input"></td>
      
      <td><input type="text" id="1" class="employee-search-input"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="2" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="3" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="4" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="5" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="6" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="7" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="8" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="9" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="10" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="11" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="12" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="13" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="14" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="15" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="16" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="17" class="employee-search-input" ></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="employee-click">
     <tr>
                        <th>NO</th>
      <th>SVC NO</th>
      <th>RANK</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>YEAR</th>
      <th>SYSTEM</th>
      <th>COURSE</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>10</th>
      
                       
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>







<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "testdb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;

$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
 0 => 'no', 
 1 => 'svcno',
 2 => 'pangkat',
 3 => 'name',
 4=> 'year',
 5 => 'system',
 6 => 'course',
 7 => 'f1',
 8 => 'f2',
 9=> 'f3',
 10 => 'f3',
 11 => 'f4',
 12 => 'f5',
 13 => 'f6',
 14 => 'f7',
 15 => 'f8',
 16 => 'f9',
 17 => 'f10',
 18 => 'f11',
);



// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT no";
$sql.=" FROM av";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("dataBiodata.php: get biodata");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


$sql = "SELECT no,svcno,pangkat,name,year,system,course,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11";
$sql.=" FROM av WHERE 1=1";
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  no LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][0]['search']['value']."%' ";    
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  svcno LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][1]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  pangkat LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][2]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  name LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][3]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  year LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][4]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][5]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  system LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][5]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][6]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  course LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][6]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][7]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  f1 LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][7]['search']['value']."%' ";
}
if( !empty($requestData['columns'][8]['search']['value']) ){
 $sql.=" AND  f2 LIKE '".$requestData['columns'][8]['search']['value']."%' ";
}



$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("dataBiodata.php: get biodata");
$totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result. 
$sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
/* $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains column index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc  */ 
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("dataBiodata.php: get biodata1");
 

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
 $nestedData=array(); 
 $nestedData[] = $row["no"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["svcno"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["pangkat"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["name"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["year"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["system"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["course"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["f1"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["f2"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f3"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f4"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f5"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f6"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f7"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f8"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f9"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f10"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["f11"];

 $data[] = $nestedData;
 

}



$json_data = array(
   "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
   "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
   "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
   "data"            => $data   // total data array
   );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format


?>
```

this is the full code. anyone know how to do it, please do not hesitate to share with me.

Comment: Without `HTML` how we do this ?

Comment: We need to see the HTML code also, and I would include into tags the Jquery or javascript tag. I think PHP doesn't match in this question.